# Rails: Dynamic :finder_sql possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My architecture looks like this (simplified): I've got users with different privileges that create posts that undergo a certain lifecycle (created, reviewed, closed, stuff like that...).

Speaking in rails terms, a `class User has_many :posts`, but I want the users to see posts depending on their privileges. If a user is privileged, he should be able to see all posts, if not I want him to see only posts that have already been reviewed plus all of his own posts.

Right now, the Post model has a class method `for_user(user)` that simply checks the users privileges and returns the according posts. I understand, that's probalby not the Rails-way to do that, and I was wondering if it could be done something like that:

```
class User
  has_many :posts, :finder_sql => finder
  #[...]
  def finder
    if self.has_privileges? #simplified...
      all
    else
      where( '[...]' )
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as rails expects the :finder_sql to be a string and a string only. Is there any other way to create the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something very similar in my current application, and I've found that using CanCan [makes it very easy](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records).

Granted, it might take a bit more effort to move your privileges logic over to CanCan, but it does add a lot of flexibilty. If nothing else, you could have a look at the source to see how he does it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to create an alias method "all_posts" and then define your own posts method that uses it:

```
class User
    has_many :all_posts, :class_name => "Post"

    def posts
       self.has_priviledges? ? self.all_posts : self.all_posts.where(...)
    end
end
```

This has the disadvantage of losing some of the caching ActiveRecord does for you.  For instance, if you called user.all_posts twice, only the first would call sql, but calling user.posts twice could possibly call sql both times if the where clause is used.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `has_many` association (which adds a bunch of setter methods, as well as getters), simply define a method (which you've more or less already done):

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :posts # written by the user

   # Posts the user can see
   def posts_visible_to
     if has_privileges?
        Post.all
     else
        posts
     end
   end

end
```

PS you spelled 'privileges' wrongly... :)